# VBA - Extract Particular Folder Name from Path

Tags: vba, folderbrowserdialog

I have the following code but I need to adjust. I want the user to select a particular folder from within a project. Imagine the path "C:\Project\SomeOtherFolder\WINDOW". The below code only fills the text box if the have selected the "WINDOW" folder. I'm just using this as a check for the user, but I actually want the text box to fill with "Project".

```
Using fb As New FolderBrowserDialog
    If fb.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK AndAlso _
    (IO.Path.GetFileName(fb.SelectedPath) = "WINDOW") Then
        TextBox1.Text = IO.Path.GetFileName(fb.SelectedPath)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Using
```

How can I accomplish this please? Many Thanks!!!

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused. You want the **Project** ? Or anything after **C:\\** till the next **\\** you can find in the path?

Comment: @PaulFrancis Hi, basically the user will have to select a path in the format "*\SomeProjectName\\*\WINDOW" and I need to return "SomeProjectName". So for whatever "Window" folder they select, I need the folder two-up. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Is **WINDOW** always the file name?

Comment: Yes it is. They must always select a folder by that name. And the project name will always be two folders behind.

Comment: Is this VBA or C#? With VBA I might be able to give you a solution. The basic is use a current structure, use IF to make sure the WINDOW is the last part of the path. Use a Split function and then UBound(theArray) - 2 would give you the two up folder name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This UDF, should give you what you need. I have created the function to return the name of the folder up from a specific folder location. I have included some optional parameters so you could (if required) change the requirement.

```
Public Function GetFolderName(FolderPath As String, _
                              Optional endPath As String = "WINDOW", _
                              Optional moveUp As Integer = 2) As String
    Dim tmpArr() As String, retStr As String

    tmpArr = Split(FolderPath, "\")

    If InStr(FolderPath, endPath) <> 0 And moveUp <= UBound(tmpArr) Then
        retStr = tmpArr(UBound(tmpArr) - moveUp)
    End If

    GetFolderName = retStr
End Function
```

So the code walk through. You send in the Path you obtain in the previous step and then you simply call the function as,

```
TextBox1.Text = GetFolderName(fb.SelectedPath)
'Or - However this is redundant as the Optional Parameters are declared as such by default
TextBox1.Text = GetFolderName(fb.SelectedPath, "WINDOW", 2)
```

The above would populate your text box as "Project". Hope this helps !